# Finite models for torsion-free lattices

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, lie-groups, symmetric-spaces

Let $G$ be a real, connected, semisimple Lie group and $\Gamma < G$ a torsion-free lattice. Then does there exist a finite $CW$-model for $B\Gamma$?

I know this to be true in many instances (e.g. when $\Gamma$ is uniform, when $G=\mathrm{SO}_0(n,1)$ or when $\mathrm{rank}_{\mathbb R}(G) \geq 2$ and $\Gamma$ is irreducible). In these instances, there always exist certain "canonical" finite CW-models for $B\Gamma$.

However, I am unaware of the situation for *general* such lattices, hence the question.

Comment: I guess many (all?) cases were done in the 70's by Borel-Serre (at least when $G$ has finite center): there's a model that's a compact manifold (with boundary). I'd thought it was known in general, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I am pretty certain that Borel-Serre constructed their finite models only for torsion-free, *arithmetic* lattices.

Comment: Let $\Gamma$ be such a lattice, and assume $G$ has trivial center (if $G$ has finite center this is no restriction). Then there is a unique product decomposition $G=G_1\times \dots G_n$ such that $\Gamma$ meets $G_i$ in an irreducible lattice. Passing to the overgroup of finite index generated by projections, we can reduce to the irreducible case. Then rank $\ge 2$ is fine (probably by arithmeticity + Borel-Serre), remains rank 1. This case is certainly OK too (removing a disjoint family of horoballs and modding out directly yields a manifold with boundary).

Comment: There is a Ph.D. thesis, I don't remember now exactly by whom, whose main result is the existence of compactifications in the rank $1$ case (basically generalizing the situation for hyperbolic lattices in the way that you described). The Lie groups I am interested in are all the real points of an algebraic group, so they all have finite center anyways.

Comment: I think your argument shows only that each $\Gamma$ *virtually* has a finite CW-model, i.e that there exists a finite-index subgroup $\Gamma' < \Gamma$ possessing a finite CW-model.

Comment: *"I think your argument shows only that each $\Gamma$ virtually..."* No, I was careful on that point: I project the lattices on factors, so I embed $\Gamma$ into a larger torsion-free lattice which is a direct product (I said "**overgroup**").

Comment: I think for Lie groups you should say "Raghunathan" where you said "Borel-Serre".

Comment: @StefanWitzel thanks for correcting. Indeed, I had in mind later papers of Borel and Serre. The statement is very precisely stated in Raghunathan's 1968 paper you're quoting.

Comment: I am afraid that I still don't understand the argument. It is clear to me that $G_i$ can be chosen such that each $\Gamma_i =G_i \cap \Gamma$ is irreducible. Moreover, the group $\Gamma' = \Gamma_1 \times \dots \times \Gamma_n$ has a finite CW-model, since each factor is irreducible torsion-free and therefore has one. It is also clear to me that $\Gamma$ is *commensurable* to $\Gamma'$, which is why $\Gamma$ virtually has a finite model as well. It is also clear that both $\Gamma$ and $\Gamma'$ embed as subgroups in the big group $\Gamma''$ generated by the projections of $\Gamma$.

Comment: However, neither do I understand why $\Gamma$ must have finite index in $\Gamma''$ nor why $\Gamma''$ has a finite CW-model, which is what I understand your argument to be.

Comment: @H1ghfiv3 This is slightly off-topic but you could avoid the technicalities by contenting yourself with a finitely *dominated* model for $B\Gamma$: Since $\Gamma$ has finite geometric dimension and a model for $B\Gamma$ of finite type, it has a finitely dominated one (Geoghegan, Prop 7.2.13).

Comment: @H1ghfiv3 I'm not sure I see your problem with YCor's argument. $\Gamma''$ is a discrete overgroup of $\Gamma'$, which is a lattice, right? The index is the quotient of the covolumes, so on particular it is finite. So $\Gamma''$ spits into factors to which you can apply the "references", so they have finite models. A finite direct product of groups with finite models has a finite model. Finally $\Gamma$ is a finite index subgroup of $\Gamma''$ so it has a finite model as well.

Comment: I suppose $\Gamma''$ might have torsion, so replace "finite model" by "proper, cocompact action on a contractible CW-complex". Since $\Gamma$ itself is torsion-free, you get the same conclusion.

Comment: How do you conclude that $\Gamma''$ splits into irreducible factors ?

Comment: @StefanWitzel indeed I claimed that the projection $\Gamma_i$ of $G_i$ is torsion-free, but this is not true. To give an example, choose two irreducible lattices $\Lambda_i$, $i=1,2$, with nontrivial homomorphisms $\pi_i:\Lambda_i\to C_2$, with $\Lambda_1$, $\mathrm{Ker}(\pi_2)$ torsion-free, but $\Lambda_2$ not torsion-free. It's easy to find such examples, e.g., as finite index subgroups of $\mathrm{PSL}_k(\mathbf{Z})$ for any $k\ge 2$. Choose $\Gamma=\{(x,y)\in\Lambda_1\times\Lambda_2:\pi_1(x)=\pi_2(y)\}$. Then it's torsion-free, but $\Gamma_2=\Lambda_2$ is not torsion-free.

Comment: Because the torsion-free setting is unpleasantly unstable, I think the right statement to prove would be: *Let $G$ be a semisimple Lie group with finite center, let $K$ be a maximal compact subgroup and $X=G/K$ (for every $G$-invariant Riemannian metric this is a symmetric space of non-compact type). Let $\Gamma$ be a lattice in $G$. Then there exists a $\Gamma$-invariant $\dim(X)$-dimensional submanifold "with corners" of $X$ on which $\Gamma$ acts cocompactly.*

Comment: @H1ghfiv3: my understanding was that $\Gamma''$ is the product of projections of $\Gamma$ to the $G_i$s. So it splits by definition.

Comment: @YCor: Yes, or using Raghunathan's approach one can use Morse-theory to produce a CW-complex along the way. In any case I think proper cocompact actions are what one wants and if the group happens to be torsion-free then it has a finite model. Thanks for the explicit example!

Comment: I apologise for being so inquisitive, but why is the *projection* again an irreducible lattice ? It is clear to me that the *intersection* with each factor is one, but the *intersection* and the *projection* need not agree, as already visible in YCor's example.

Comment: Incidentally, it is an open problem that if G is a torsion free group whose finite index subgroup H admits a finite K(H,1) then there exists a finite K(G,1).

Comment: @MoisheKohan Yes that was also mentioned by the OP elsewhere in a comment. But of course you wouldn't be expected to read all the comments on this post :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact, more is true and you do not need separate arguments for rank 1 and higher rank.

The following is Theorem 13.1(i) in the book of Ballmann, Gromov and Schroeder "Manifolds of nonpositive curvature":

Suppose that $(M,g)$ is a complete real-analytic Riemannian manifold of nonpositive curvature and finite volume. Then $M$ is tame: It is diffeomorphic to the interior of a compact manifold with boundary $M'$.

Moreover, the proof shows that $M'$ can be realized as a submanifold (with boundary) of $M$.

Applying this to the locally-symmetric space $(M,g)=X/\Gamma$, where $\Gamma$ is a torsion-free lattice  in the isometry group of a nonpositively curved symmetric space $X$, after triangulating $M'$, we obtain a finite model for $\Gamma$.

Comment: Just one question: Do they also show that locally symmetric spaces of non-positive curvature are analytic ?

Comment: @H1ghfiv3 I think this will come from the fact that your groups are real points of algebraic groups.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Neat! You don't happen to know of any generalization to other lattices in locally compact CAT(0)-groups (like algebraic groups over local fields)? I'm asking because in certain cases there is an answer similar to the one I sketched, but it uses heavy machinery (reduction theory) and it is an open problem to understand how much of that one could do purely geometrically.

Comment: @H1ghfiv3 There are many arguments, for instance, use an equivariant  isometric embedding in the symmetric space of $SL(n, R)$, which would have to be real analytic. Or use the fact that the metric on the symmetric space is obtained by applying action of it's isometry group (which is real analytic) to a K- invariant metric on the tangent soace at the point corresponding to K in G/K.

Comment: @StefanWitzel That I do not know, Gromov's argument is differential-geometric.

Comment: Do you know if there's a statement covering both results? Namely in the same setting but applying to possibly non-torsion-free lattices?

Comment: @YCor No, I do not. One can go through Gromov's argument and check if it can be modified to deal with orbifolds. My guess is that it works. Gelander, I think, would be the person to ask since he improved Gromov's proof.

Answer (score 4):

I'll try to summarize YCor's comments into an answer (using big guns): Let $G$ be the real points of an algebraic group (a restriction by the OP in the comments) and assume $\Gamma$ irreducible.

Then [Raghunathan](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01425317) shows that the answer is "yes" if $\Gamma$ is arithmetic. Margulis (Discrete subgroups of semisimple Lie groups) says that $\Gamma$ will be arithmetic if $G$ has rank at least $2$ (this is the sum over the ranks of the almost-factors). This leaves the case where $G$ is a single rank-1 factor. In that case $\Gamma\backslash G/K$ is a finite volume hyperbolic manifold from which one can cut off the cusps, see Theorem 12.7.2 in Ratcliffe, "Foundations of hyperbolic manifolds".

Edit: I'll also try to summarize the discussion about the reduction to the irreducible case. Suppose $G = G_1 \times \ldots \times G_k$ and the image of $\Gamma$ under the projection to $G_i$ is an irreducible lattice $\Gamma_i$. Let $\Gamma'' = \Gamma_1 \times \ldots \times \Gamma_k$. Now the above discussion shows that each $\Gamma_i$ acts properly and cocompactly on a contractible CW-complex $X_i$. Hence $\Gamma''$ acts properly and cocompactly on $X = X_1 \times \ldots \times X_k$. This action restricts to a proper and cocompact action of $\Gamma$. If $\Gamma$ happens to be torsion-free, the action is free and $\Gamma \backslash X$ is a finite model for $B\Gamma$.

Comment: I probably should have clarified that the irreducible case was clear to me, precisley because of the arguments that you employ. What I currently fail to understand is YCor's reasoning for general (reducible) lattices. Thanks anyways!

Comment: Your original question was a "reference request", I think these are the references. The reduction to the irreducible case may be  technical but I don't think anything profound happens (no new "references").

Comment: The reduction on the irreducible case that YCor employed might be correct, I am not yet convinced (but that doesn't mean anything, I am not an expert in this area and all of what I've been asking might be very obvious to experts on Lie groups). However, the question on whether a *general* torsion-free discrete group $\Gamma$ has a finite CW-model for $B\Gamma$ whenever this *virtually* is the case is highly non-trivial, and as far as I know still open. A statement conforming this would indeed be of some profoundness (at least to me)

Comment: Oh yes, I didn't mean to claim anything in that direction. What you can get on abstract grounds is finite domination as I mentioned above. I didn't want to think about the details of YCor's reduction, but I probably should.

Comment: @H1ghfiv3 My attempt was to embed $\Gamma$ as subgroup of finite index in a product, so I didn't try to get finiteness of $B\Gamma$ from a finite index subgroup, but from a finite index overgroup. The problem with my approach is that the overgroup can have torsion even if the small group doesn't.

Comment: So here is the thing that I haven't quite sorted out: what if $\Gamma < G_1 \times G_2$ has discrete image in $G_1$ but dense image in $G_2$? This can happen for instance by choosing the wrong decomposition of $G_1 \times G_2 = \mathbb{R}^2$. I would like to say that it can *only* happen by choosing a wrong decomposition.

Comment: It is not clear to me why you can suppose, without loss of much generality, that each *projection* is an irreducible lattice (it is clear for the *intersection*).

Comment: @H1ghfiv3 Suppose $\Gamma < G_1 \times G_2$ with $\textrm{pr}_1(\Gamma)$ discrete (because $\Gamma$ is reducible). Then $\textrm{pr}_1(\Gamma)$ is a lattice and $\Gamma \cap G_2$ is a lattice and also $\overline{\textrm{pr}_2(\Gamma)}$ has finite covolume and $\Gamma \cap G_1$ is discrete, agreed? Now I think showing that $\Gamma \cap G_1$ has finite covolume is "equivalent" to showing that $\overline{\textrm{pr}_2(\Gamma)}$ is discrete. So if it is clear to you that $\Gamma'$ is a lattice, it should also be clear that $\Gamma''$ is a lattice.

Comment: Yes, I should have phrased my question more precisely: Why is it clear to you that $pr_i(\Gamma)$ is *irreducible* as a lattice ?

Comment: @H1ghfiv3 Well, in general of course it's not, apply induction.

Comment: Right! Now I get it. You proceed by induction.